# Adding tooltips to a table with fixed header and left columns

Tags: html-table, tooltip, scrollable, fixed-header-tables

I am trying to add tooltips to a scrollable table that has fixed headers and left columns.  When I add the tooltip the cell no longer hides behind the fixed headers and columns when the table is scrolled.

```
<HTML>
<HEAD>
<STYLE>
.gradebooktable {
  overflow: auto;
  height: 100px;
  width: 400px
}

table {
  table-layout: fixed;
  border-width: 0;
  border-spacing: 0;
}

td {
  padding: 3px;
  white-space: nowrap;
  border-right: 1px solid #ccc;
}

th {
  background: #999;
}

th.pinned {
  position: relative; 
  z-index: 20;        
  background: #ccc;
}

td.pinned {
  background: #eee;
}

.tooltip{
  position:relative;
}

.tooltipcomment{
  display:none;
  position:absolute; 
  z-index:10;
  border:1px;
  background-color:white;
  border-style:solid;
  border-width:1px;
  border-color:blue;
  padding:3px;
  color:red; 
  top:20px; 
  left:20px;
}

.tooltip:hover span.tooltipcomment{
  display:block;
}

</style>
</STYLE>
</HEAD>
<BODY>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<SCRIPT>
$( function() {
$('#gradebooktable').scroll( function() {
      var translate = "translate(0," + this.scrollTop + "px)";
      $("table thead th:not(.pinned)").css('transform', translate);

      translate = "translate(" + this.scrollLeft + "px,0)";
      $("table tbody .pinned").css('transform', translate);

      translate = "translate(" + this.scrollLeft + "px," + this.scrollTop + "px)";
      $("table thead th.pinned").css('transform', translate);
    }
);  
});
</SCRIPT>
  <div id="gradebooktable" class="gradebooktable">
    <table>
      <thead>
        <tr>
          <th class="pinned">Col 0</th>
          <th class="pinned">Col 1</th>
          <th>Col 2</th>
          <th>Col 3</th>
          <th>Col 4</th>
          <th>Col 5</th>
          <th>Col 6</th>
          <th>Col 7</th>
          <th>Col 8</th>
          <th>Col 9</th>
        </tr>
      </thead>
      <tbody>
        <tr>
          <td class="pinned">First Cell</td>
          <td class="pinned">Second Cell</td>
         <td class="tooltip">Another Cell
                  <span class="tooltipcomment">Here is a comment</span></td>
          <td>Another Cell</td>
          <td>Another Cell</td>
          <td>Another Cell</td>
          <td>Another Cell</td>
          <td>Another Cell</td>
          <td>Another Cell</td>
          <td>Another Cell</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td class="pinned">First Cell</td>
          <td class="pinned">Second Cell</td>
          <td>Another Cell</td>
          <td>Another Cell</td>
          <td>Another Cell</td>
          <td>Another Cell</td>
          <td>Another Cell</td>
          <td>Another Cell</td>
          <td>Another Cell</td>
          <td>Another Cell</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td class="pinned">First Cell</td>
          <td class="pinned">Second Cell</td>
          <td>Another Cell</td>
          <td>Another Cell</td>
          <td>Another Cell</td>
          <td>Another Cell</td>
          <td>Another Cell</td>
          <td>Another Cell</td>
          <td>Another Cell</td>
          <td>Another Cell</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td class="pinned">First Cell</td>
          <td class="pinned">Second Cell</td>
          <td>Another Cell</td>
          <td>Another Cell</td>
          <td>Another Cell</td>
          <td>Another Cell</td>
          <td>Another Cell</td>
          <td>Another Cell</td>
          <td>Another Cell</td>
          <td>Another Cell</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td class="pinned">First Cell</td>
          <td class="pinned">Second Cell</td>
          <td>Another Cell</td>
          <td>Another Cell</td>
          <td>Another Cell</td>
          <td>Another Cell</td>
          <td>Another Cell</td>
          <td>Another Cell</td>
          <td>Another Cell</td>
          <td>Another Cell</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td class="pinned">First Cell</td>
          <td class="pinned">Second Cell</td>
          <td>Another Cell</td>
          <td>Another Cell</td>
          <td>Another Cell</td>
          <td>Another Cell</td>
          <td>Another Cell</td>
          <td>Another Cell</td>
          <td>Another Cell</td>
          <td>Another Cell</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td class="pinned">First Cell</td>
          <td class="pinned">Second Cell</td>
          <td>Another Cell</td>
          <td>Another Cell</td>
          <td>Another Cell</td>
          <td>Another Cell</td>
          <td>Another Cell</td>
          <td>Another Cell</td>
          <td>Another Cell</td>
          <td>Another Cell</td>
        </tr>
      </tbody>
    </table>
    </div>
</BODY>
</HTML>
```

There is a fiddle showing the problem here:

https://jsfiddle.net/6jh60sgs/9/

What do I need to do to make the cell with the tooltip scroll behind the fixed headers and columns?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed it:  https://jsfiddle.net/k42myms3/1/

```
.gradebooktable {
  overflow: auto;
  height: 200px;
  width: 400px
}

table {
  table-layout: fixed;
  border-width: 0;
  border-spacing: 0;
}

td {
  position:relative;
  padding: 3px;
  white-space: nowrap;
  border-right: 1px solid #ccc;
}

th {
  position:relative;
  z-index:20; 
  background: #999;
}

th.pinned {
  position: relative; 
  z-index: 40;     
  background: #ccc;
}

td.pinned {
  position: relative;
  z-index: 30; 
  background: #eee; 
}

.tooltip{
  position:relative;
}

.tooltiptext{
  display:none;
  position:absolute; 
  z-index:10;
  border:1px;
  background-color:#eee;
  border-style:solid;
  border-width:1px;
  border-color:blue;
  border-radius: 6px;
  padding:3px;
  color:blue; 
  top:20px; 
  left:20px;
}

.tooltip:hover span.tooltiptext{
  display:block;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

try this instead, i've tested on your code before and working

just change your tooltip class

like this

```
.tooltip{
 position:relative;
 display: none;
 }
```

Comment: Thanks, that hides the cell when it is scrolled, but then the tooltip doesn't show up anymore.